# Trying to solve $y'=\frac{t+y}{t-y}$ by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve
$$
y^\prime=\frac{t+y}{t-y}
$$
by substitution.

Substituting $y=tv$ where $v=v(t)$ is some unknown function of $t$ we have after a of algebra
$$
v+tv^\prime=\frac{1+v^2}{1-v}.
$$

My book says that we can separate this expression to
$$
\frac{dv}{1+v^2}-\frac{vdv}{1+v^2}=\frac{dt}{t}.
$$

Can somebody show me how to arrive at the expression above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the substitution you get
\begin{eqnarray*}
v+tv^\prime=\frac{1+v}{1-v}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now move the $v$ to the RHS ... etc ... do the algebra!

Comment: Where does the $dt$ and $dv$ come from?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
v^\prime=\frac{dv}{dt}.
\end{eqnarray*}